How do I free up GPU memory when using Accelerate with Deepspeed
I am using accelerate launch with deepspeed zero stage 2 for multi gpu training and inference and am struggling to free up GPU memory.
Basically, my programme has three parts

Load first model...
-Remove all memory occupied by 1.
Load second model...
-Remove all memory occupied by 2.
Load third model...

Now between each 1 and 2 and 2 and 3 I would like to free all GPU memory occupied by the previous part (otherwise I get an out of memory error). I have tried del, gc, release_memory(), but nothing works. For an example see below:

...
model = ...
accelerator = Accelerator()

model, dataloader, optimizer = accelerator.prepare(model, dataloader, optimizer)

...

del model
accelerator.free_memory()
del accelerator
gc.collect()
torch.cuda.empty_cache()


Any help is appreciated! Thanks in advance!
I tried the following:
del model
accelerator.free_memory()
del accelerator
gc.collect()
torch.cuda.empty_cache()


But am still running out of memory and torch.cuda.memory_allocated() is unaffected.
I found this question (How to Properly Manage GPU Memory Between Successive PyTorch Training Phases using accelerate?) which describes my problem without Deepspeed, but it also doesn't have an answer.
